# Jquery updating Div error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function(){
        $('#main2').empty();
        $('#main2').load('index.php?_='+Math.random()+'    #main2').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

in the header.

My div:

```
<div id="main2">
<?php include('newsong.php'); ?>
</div>
```

it updates but i can see the whole page flick(not the index.php), instead of only the div. I have searched, but nothing is like this question. Thank you.

Comment: You can remove $("#main2").empty()  as anyway once you get the response it will update the innerHTML

Comment: May be you need request at $('#main2').load `newsong.php` not `index.php`?

Comment: Thank you abs and stdob, the suggestions did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries i found the script that work, at least for me(firefox):

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#main2").load("newsong.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#main2").load('newsong.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 9000);
     });
    </script>
```

And for the div:

```
<div id="main2">
<noscript>
<?php
include('newsong.php');
?>
</noscript>

</div>
```